# Unable to use git personal access token for webdrivermanger?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

Unable to use git personal access token to avoid 403 errors for geckodriver using webdrivermanger in jenkins!!

I can see token is never used state in git settings.

```
-Dwdm.gitHubTokenName=githubusername
-Dwdm.gitHubTokenSecret=token
```

Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your GitHub tokens in this [page](https://github.com/settings/tokens) of your account. The value of `wdm.gitHubTokenName` is the name of one of your tokens (not necessarily your GitHub user name) and `wdm.gitHubTokenSecret` is the value of that token.